# PromiseKit 3.0 chaining

Tags: swift, promisekit

I'm trying to write a function that returns a promise:

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise(1)
    .then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }.then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }
}
```

I get an error on the last then statement:

```
Declared closure result 'Void' (aka '()') is incompatible with contextual type 'AnyPromise'
```

I was under the impression that 'then' should implicitly returned a promise regardless; Is my thinking wrong? Should I just return a promise explicitly like so?:

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise(1)
    .then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }.then { _ -> Promise<AnyObject> in
        debugPrint("foo")
        return Promise(1)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise returned by `then(_:)` matches the return value of the closure.

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise(1)
    .then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }.then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }
}
```

Let me rework your method.

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    let p1: Promise<AnyObject> = Promise(1)
    let p2: Promise<Void> = p1.then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }
    let p3: Promise<Void> = p2.then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }
    return p3
}
```

You can now see the expected return type of `Promise<AnyObject>` doesn't match actual return type of `Promise<Void>`.

If you want to have a method return `Promise<AnyObject>`, then the last promise in the promise chain must return `AnyObject`.

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return firstly { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }.then { _ -> Void in
        debugPrint("foo")
    }.then { _ -> AnyObject in
        1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. Its hard to understand this from reading the source & documentation. Within the block after 'firstly' I get a weird error `Ambiguous reference to member 'debugPrint(_:separator:terminator:)` on the line `debugPrint("foo")`. However I replaced that to the following: `return Promise<AnyObject> { fulfill, reject in
            var fish = 1
        }.then { _ -> Void in
            debugPrint("foo")
        }.then { _ -> AnyObject in
            1
        }` And it works fine @JefferyThomas

Answer (score 2):

A `then` call returns whatever you specify in it's call, `Void` in your first example.

For your second attempt there, you're closer, but you're returning an unrelated `Promise`, which you've had to fulfill with `1` a second time.

Try this code instead:

```
func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
    return Promise<AnyObject> { fulfill, reject in
        return Promise<AnyObject>(1)
        .then { _ -> Void in
            debugPrint("foo")
        }.then { _ -> Void in
            debugPrint("foo")
        }
    }
}
```

This embeds the second `Promise` in the first, so now your `then`'s will run in order as well as any others you add to the promise returned by the function when it's called wherever else in your code.

Comment: Thanks @DaveWood; I'm still getting the same error though with your example. I even removed the first 'then'. Here's what I have now: `func sample() -> Promise<AnyObject> {
        return Promise<AnyObject> { fulfill, reject in
           return Promise<AnyObject>(1)
        }.then { _ -> Void in
            debugPrint("foo")
        }
    }` Any ideas?

Comment: You've changed the code again so that your `then` is on the outside promise instead of the inside promise.

Comment: Do you know why 'fulfill' doesn't have to be called in this case? @DaveWood

Comment: Actually, unless I fulfill the outer promise I get this error in my log: `Promise deallocated! This is usually a bug` @DaveWood

Comment: Actually, I'd vote for @Jeffery-Thomas's answer as being the correct one rather than mine. His produces cleaner code without having to use an internal promise or using fulfill/reject. His explanation that the return value of the last `then` must match the type of promise returned from the method is clear.